# Laravel Slack Notification response

Tags: laravel, slack-api, laravel-notification

I use the slack notification system from laravel to send messages in a channel.

I would like to access the response of the request to get the timestamp of the message posted to store it and modify the message later.

How could I get this response ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I understood that the Slack system in Laravel using the slack webhoock, we cannot get anything in the response.

To get something, we should use the chat.postMessage method instead with a slack token.

There is a package on Github which permit that :

https://github.com/beyondcode/slack-notification-channel